# Copy an image carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I have ArtworkUploader and i want to create a duplicate of the artwork image in same directory. Help me to solve this.

My Uploader:

```
class ArtworkUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    if model
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
    end
  end

  def filename
    "artwork.png"
  end
end
```

I tried with console but it doesn't work. What am i missing here?

Console:

```
> u = User.find(5)
> u.artwork.create(name: "testing.png", file: u.artwork.path)
> NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for /uploads/5/artwork/Artwork:ArtworkUploader
```

Comment: What do mean by copy do you mean modify the existing file that already uploaded

Comment: I want to get the image with my customized file_name along with the original file.

Comment: why not create another file and apply the same uploader to it

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 way I can think of you can do that

a) **VIA Versioning** : 
      create version of your file

```
  version: copy_file do 
      process :create_a_copy
  end
```

and now just define `create_a_copy` method inside your uploader which will just return the same file

This way you can have the copy of the file .I didn't understand your `custom filename` stuff  but the way you have define it your for uploader `filename` method you can do that the same for `version` as well something like this

```
   version: copy_file do 
        process :create_a_copy
        def filename
          "testing.png"
        end  
      end
```

**NOTE:** 
Not sure of the filename stuff for version file since I done it long back, but I believe the above setting of different `filename` method would work.

Adavantage :

- All File and copy are associated in one uploader
- No extra column is required on database (which is required in approach b)

Now the above approach too have some caveats in it

- Slightly more complex
- Single delete issue, delete to original uploader would delete its copy as well

b) **VIA Separate Column** : 
   They other way you can achieve that is defining a separate column called `artwork_copy` and mount the same uploader with just a slightly change in your uploader like this

```
  def filename
    if self.mounted_as == :artwork
      "artwork.png"
    else
      "testing.png"
    end
  end
```

And the way you attach the file (give that your file is stored in locally)

```
u = User.find(5)
u.artwork_copy = File.open(u.artwork) ## Just cross check
u.save
```

There is an another way you do this via do the above same

```
   u = User.find(5)
   u.artwork_copy.store!(File.open(u.artwork))
```

Now you it pretty obvious what the advantage/disadvantage of the  approach b mention above

Hope this make sense